# Javascript code doesn't work. Why?

Tags: javascript, html

The values of the buttons should change when you click on them

```
<html>
<head>

</head>


<body>

<input type = "button" value ="1" onclick="click(this);">
<input type = "button" value ="0" onclick="click(this);">
<input type = "button" value ="1" onclick="click(this);">

<script>

function click(objekt) {

if(objekt.value == 1)
    objekt.value = 0;
    else
        objekt.value = 1;

}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Please explain how to get the value on onclick event?

Comment: Is the value of "value" an integer or string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name of your function is the culprit here. you can not name your function name `"click"`, it's restricted . Change your function name, it will work.

```js
function click123(objekt) {
  if (objekt.value == 1)
    objekt.value = 0;
  else
    objekt.value = 1;

}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="click123(this);">
<input type="button" value="0" onclick="click123(this);">
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="click123(this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the spaces on

```
<input type = "button" value ="1" onclick="click(this);">
<input type = "button" value ="0" onclick="click(this);">
<input type = "button" value ="1" onclick="click(this);">
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="click(this);">
<input type="button" value="0" onclick="click(this);">
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="click(this);">
```

Also, what are the values when you change them? Try printing them out. That might help you find what you're looking for. Does it actually change to 1 or 0? Also, I know you don't need curly brackets on if statements if there is only one statement but try with curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/o0zxqq0u/

```
clickFunc = function(objekt) {
    if(objekt.value == 1)
        objekt.value = 0;
    else
        objekt.value = 1; 
}

**HTML**
<input type="button" value ="1" onclick="clickFunc(this);" />
<input type="button" value ="0" onclick="clickFunc(this);" />
<input type="button" value ="1" onclick="clickFunc(this);" />
```